# Swipe to delete function in tableview does not work properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I've just added the swipe to delete function to my tableview controller. However is doesn't work properly. It deletes the item in my Firebase Database. But it doesn't delete the row out of my tableview controller. The only way to get rid of the row is to restart the whole application. What am I missing in my code?

```
var CourtDictionary = [String: Courts]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)

 let Platz = self.Platzlist[indexPath.row]

    if let CourtID = Platz.PlatzID {

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Sportplatz").child(CourtID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Fehler beim Löschen",error!)
                return
            }
            self.CourtDictionary.removeValue(forKey: CourtID)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })



    }
```

The editRow function is set to true. The app is not crashing at all. But the delete function seems not to be called in terms of the tableview controller.

Comment: I tried it, but I got even worse. I couldn't swipe up and down after I pressed delete. The cell wasn't deleted as well.
Any other idea?